# Using blender to animate and annotate pdf

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to create commentaries on bad research articles and I'm not sure i'm using the right tools. My method so far:

convert pdf to images
import images as layers
animate camera movements to the regions i am reading in voiceover

The rendering seems very slow even on the most minimal settings. I get the feeling I am using completely the wrong tool given that most pdf readers can render pages instantly.

Is blender completely the wrong thing to use for this task? Would anyone suggest a better tool? many thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it's the wrong tool, yes.  I would use a PDF reader that allows annotation and something like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) to record.  Have OBS record the window with the PDF reader as you scroll and annotate using the PDF reader's tools.

Comment: thanks. I'm really looking for an editor so i can align my voiceover with highlighted text segments

Comment: You can record your takes with OBS and then use it as a video editor to assemble the takes you like.  A lot of YouTube videos are made that way,